# Is fglrx incompatible with xUbuntu ? (14.04)

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, fglrx

I had some video driver issues previously , my laptop used to get struck after I (close the lid) put it on standby and when I try to start the screen doesn't show up. So I installed `libcheese*` and `fglrx` which seemed to fix the problem but now I've installed xUbuntu desktop for a change and now the problem is back. I tried installing fglrx-updates but it deletes the previous fglrx (strangely fglrx and fglrx-updates are mutually exclusive) . Sometimes my screen starts up after standby and sometimes it doesn't (most of time it doesn't). The only option I'am left with is hard boot which is really annoying. I'am wondering if fglrx is incompatible with xUbuntu how do I solve this?